# Máscara para CPF e CNPJ no mesmo campo

Tags: jquery, mask

Olá, busquei por essa dúvida nas perguntas, porém não a consegui encontrar. Pois bem, gostaria de fazer com que um campo tivesse as máscaras de cpf e cnpj dependendo da quantidade de caracteres digitados. Aqui não dá totalmente certo, pois com vários testes que fiz aqui, esse meu código não deu resultado que preciso. Não sei se devo apenas alterar, ou se preciso fazer outro.

Segue o código:

```
$("#cpfcnpj").keypress(function(){
    $("#cpfcnpj").unmask();
    var tamanho = $("#cpfcnpj").val().length;

    if(tamanho == 11){
        $("#cpfcnpj").mask("999.999.99-99");
    } else if(tamanho == 14){
        $("#cpfcnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    }                   
});
```

Obs: Estou usando esse [plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html).

Comment: Segue o tutorial `https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask` e cdn `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.inputmask` até mais.

Comment: Diego você viu a minha resposta ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Tente usar o operador maior igual ou menor igual, segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
$("#cpfcnpj").keydown(function(){
    try {
        $("#cpfcnpj").unmask();
    } catch (e) {}

    var tamanho = $("#cpfcnpj").val().length;

    if(tamanho < 11){
        $("#cpfcnpj").mask("999.999.999-99");
    } else {
        $("#cpfcnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    }

    // ajustando foco
    var elem = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        // mudo a posição do seletor
        elem.selectionStart = elem.selectionEnd = 10000;
    }, 0);
    // reaplico o valor para mudar o foco
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).val(currentValue);
});
```

> Exemplo no JSFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/z5qmwn1d/

Comment: Não consegui aqui Hiago :(

Comment: Vou colocar o exemplo no JSFiddler

Comment: Pronto editei a resposta, encontrei um erro no código mas já coloquei um exemplo no JSFiddler

Comment: Descenessário esse if no else...

Comment: Muito obrigado Hiago, tá funcionando perfeitamente aqui!

Comment: @LuisHenrique concordo, quando editei eu nem reparei.

Comment: @HiagoSouza Coloquei em meu projeto mas não funcionou, precisa colocar referencia para algum arquivo javascript?

Comment: @MauricioFerraz, você precisa ter [jQuery](https://jquery.org/) no seu projeto.

Comment: Consegui usando um plugin: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122147/plugin-da-digitalbush-para-mascara-cnpj-e-cpf-no-mesmo-campo/122152#122152

Comment: Aqui ele está voltando um caractere quando passa no ponto :(

Comment: Estranho Lucas, tentou usar o exemplo do JSFiddler

Comment: Testei e não funciona corretamente, ele volta uma casa quando está digitando, teste a sequencia 123456789 e verá o erro.

Comment: Tentei realizar um teste e está com um bug

Comment: Qual o bug @DenisRudneideSouza? Está fazendo uso da mesma biblioteca? O bug é reproduzido no exemplo que deixei no fiddler?

Comment: Testei pelo fiddle, ao colocar o quarto digito ele move para o fim, desconfigurando o resultado final

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza realmente, pode ter sido alguma atualização de browser, antes funcionava normalmente. Editei a resposta com a correção desse bug.

Comment: Podem existir anomalias no evento 'focusout' ao utilizar esta solução, implementei uma melhoria: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/269671/744

@DenisRudneideSouza

Comment: Ao pressionar o tab, a máscara desformata o campo.

Comment: @HiagoSouza a linha `} else if(tamanho >= 11) {` é desnecessária troque por `} else {`

Comment: @AugustoVasques você tem razão, obrigado pela observação!

Comment: Muito útil meu amigo, obrigado

Comment: Seria melhor usar a resposta do @Matheus Miranda logo abaixo, pois está de acordo com a documentação do plugin ;-)

Answer (score 49):

Na documentação dele já tem um exemplo que é: [On-the-fly mask change](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#on-the-fly-mask-changes), ele usou exemplo com ***CEP***, só basta trocar para ***CPF***.

Veja o código abaixo, como funciona o ***CPF*** e ***CNPF*** no mesmo campo:

```js
var options = {
    onKeyPress: function (cpf, ev, el, op) {
        var masks = ['000.000.000-000', '00.000.000/0000-00'];
        $('.cpfOuCnpj').mask((cpf.length > 14) ? masks[1] : masks[0], op);
    }
}

$('.cpfOuCnpj').length > 11 ? $('.cpfOuCnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', options) : $('.cpfOuCnpj').mask('000.000.000-00#', options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input class="cpfOuCnpj" value="11111111111" type="text">
```

Documentação: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Se preferir em JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znuph72f/375/

Segue a discussão: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/53

Comment: Essa deveria ser a resposta correta, já que o marcado acima apresenta bugs com backspace, ao tentar apagar o que foi digitado.

Comment: Matheus Miranda, muito bom, estava precisando de uma solução dessa, entrei aqui no forum e vi a sua solução e te informo que estou usando ela cara. Muito simples e pequena. Parabéns.

Comment: @EdeGerSil que bom você gostou e seja feliz :D

Comment: Esta deve ser a solução correta. Limpa e de acordo com a documentação.

Answer (score 13):

A solução proposta não funciona muito bem porque a condição booleana escrita pode apresentar anomalias no evento 'focusout'.

proponho a seguinte solução:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '[data-mask-for-cpf-cnpj]', function (e) {

    var digit = e.key.replace(/\D/g, '');

    var value = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

    var size = value.concat(digit).length;

    $(this).mask((size <= 11) ? '000.000.000-00' : '00.000.000/0000-00');
});
```

Esta solução é melhor nos seguintes aspectos:

1. Trabalha o seletor tendo o documento como escopo, ou seja, caso o elemento seja inserido posteriormente ao carregamento da DOM continua funcional.
2. Remove a necessidade de utilizar a função 'setTimeout' para ajustar o seletor.
3. Utiliza o atributo 'data-mask-for-cpf-cnpj' para criar um Javascript não-obstrutivo, que deixa o código limpo, ou seja seu elemento ficaria bem elegante:

   **ex.: < input type="text" data-mask-for-cpf-cnpj />**

Comment: Melhor solução possível! Obrigado man.

Comment: incrível sua solução... resolveu meu problema e anda criei algumas variações pra telefone etc...

Answer (score 5):

Você esta usando que Plugin? caso seja o **[Maskedinput](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)** da **Digitalbush** segue um exemplo:

```
$(".hibridCpf").on('focusin',function(){
    var target = $(this);
    var val = target.val();
    target.unmask();
    val = val.split(".").join("");
    val = val.split("-").join("");
    val = val.split("/").join("");
    target.val(val);
});
$(".hibridCpf").on('focusout',function(){
    var target = $(this);
    var val = target.val();
    val = val.split(".").join("");
    val = val.split("-").join("");
    val = val.split("/").join("");
    if (val.length==11) {
        target.mask("999.999.999-99");
        target.val(val);
    } else {
        if (val.length==14) {
            target.mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
            target.val(val);
        } else {
            target.val('');
        }
    }
});
```

> Teste esse exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chinnonsantos/k7ojrg84/).

Essa solução server também para campos de CEP onde o usuário pode informar um Código postal brasileiro ou americano, usando uma lógica similar...

PS: Um plugin de mascara que recomendo e passei a utilizar é o **Mask Plugin** criado pelo Brasileiro **[@igorescobar (Github)](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)**, ele reuni o **[Mask Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)** e **[Mask Money](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/)** em um só com mais opções de personalização, vale a pena conferir!

Também existe uma solução mais simples para sua pergunta postada pelo [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray) nessa [**pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122147/plugin-da-digitalbush-para-mascara-cnpj-e-cpf-no-mesmo-campo), porem usa outro Plugin chamado [**Input Mask**](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask).

Answer (score 3):

Desse jeito funcionou pra mim. No `focusin` você remove a máscara, no `focusout` você aplica a máscara, removendo os caratéres especiais.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".cpfCnpj").unmask();
  $(".cpfCnpj").focusout(function() {
    $(".cpfCnpj").unmask();
    var tamanho = $(".cpfCnpj").val().replace(/\D/g, '').length;
    if (tamanho == 11) {
      $(".cpfCnpj").mask("999.999.999-99");
    } else if (tamanho == 14) {
      $(".cpfCnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    }
  });
  $(".cpfCnpj").focusin(function() {
    $(".cpfCnpj").unmask();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#cpfcnpj').mask('000.000.000-00', {
  onKeyPress : function(cpfcnpj, e, field, options) {
    const masks = ['000.000.000-000', '00.000.000/0000-00'];
    const mask = (cpfcnpj.length > 14) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
    $('#cpfcnpj').mask(mask, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <label>Insira um CPF ou CNPJ: </label>
  <input name="cpfcnpj" id="cpfcnpj" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Passei por este problemas também, onde era necessário ter uma mascara dinâmica que pudesse mudar de forma para CPF ou CNPJ. E como estou a usar apenas Javascript utilizei uma biblioteca que usa Vanilla Javascript para criar mascaras.

## imask js

Usando o [imask](https://unmanner.github.io/imaskjs/) você pode criar uma mascara dinâmica passando um array para a propriedade `mask` onde contém a definição de suas mascaras. E como regra de mudança simplesmente defina o máximo de caracteres que uma das mascara vai conter em `maxLenght`, veja um exemplo:

```js
var maskCpfOuCnpj = IMask(document.getElementById('cpfcnpj'), {
   mask:[
    {
     mask: '000.000.000-00',
     maxLength: 11
    },
    {
     mask: '00.000.000/0000-00'
    }
   ]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<input id="cpfcnpj" type="text" placeholder="digite o CPF ou CNPJ" name="cpfcnpj" required>
```

O `maxLength` da mascara do CPF foi especificado para 11 dígitos, claro que podem haver variações, mas seria fácil implementar essas variações para definir a mascara.

A ideia do `IMask` é o processamento do `input` simplesmente comparando o estado de *antes* e *depois*, sendo as mudanças de estados obtidas através do evento `keydown` que fornece o estado dos valores.

Veja um [guia](https://unmanner.github.io/imaskjs/guide.html) para aprender mais sobre o imask js.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz essa, simples, só com Javascript. Basta por a Classe no input.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cpfcnpj");
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){ x[i].addEventListener('focus',function(e){ document.getElementById(e.target.id).select(); }); }
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { x[i].addEventListener('keyup', myFunction, false); }
function myFunction(e)
{
    x = '';
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46){
        return false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode >= 48 || e.keyCode <= 57){

        var id = e.target.id;
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('maxlength',18);
        var str = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g,''); 
        //var str = str.replace(/^0+/, ''); 
        var len = str.length; // 
        if(len==11){ 
            x = str.substr(0, 3) + '.' + str.substr(3, 3) + '.' + str.substr(6, 3) + '-' + str.substr(9, 2);; // 510.791.784-49
        }else if(len>11 && len<15){ 
            x = str.substr(0, 2) + '.' + str.substr(2, 3) + '.' + str.substr(5, 3) + '/' + str.substr(8, 4) + '-' + str.substr(12, 2);  // 04.498.492/0001-67
        }else{
            x = str;
        }
        document.getElementById(id).value = x;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="doc" type="text" class="cpfcnpj">
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://coday.netlify.app/mascara-cpf-cnpj/