# Plugin da digitalbush para mascara CNPJ e CPF no mesmo campo

Tags: jquery, html

Eu uso o plugin abaixo nos meus campos html para fazer a mascara, me surgiu a necessidade de colocar a mascara de cnpj e cpf no mesmo campos, alguém sabe como fazer isso com esse plugin?

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
$("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
$("#cnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Com outro plugin eu sei q da p fazer, poderia colocar o formato do cpf e cnpj.

Comment: Então o que gosto nesse é que a aparência dele é perfeita, pois quando vc clica no campo ele aparece, diferente de outros que vai aparecendo conforme vai digitando. Não sei se eu colocar outro plugin vai conflitar com esse plugin que já esta sendo usado em outros campos.

Comment: @Bacco eu não consegui fazer funcionar com a resposta que vc mencionou ser duplicada, la não tem referencia do plugin que esta sendo usado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar o plugin [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) para mascarar uma entrada com formatos diferentes. O código a seguir define dois formatos o primeiro para o cpf e o segundo para o cnpj, quando o usuário digitar o 15º a máscara mudará de cpf para cpnj isso é feito com a opção `keepStatic: true` que 'segura' o formato até a entrada casar com o próximo.

```
$("#doc").inputmask({mask: ['999.999.999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99'], keepStatic: true });
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar ele agora.

Comment: rray ele funcionou perfeitamente, sabe me dizer se existe possibilidade dele conflitar com o outro plugin? Existe algum problema em usar os dois na mesma pagina?

Comment: @MauricioFerraz acreito que não pode usar tranquilo só não confundir os nome que são parecidos xD

Comment: rray me tire apenas mais uma duvida, vc sabe se existe a opção da mascara aparecer no campo apenas quando ele for clicado invés do hover (quando coloca a seta do mouse em cima)?

Comment: @MauricioFerraz tem sim, adicione `, showMaskOnHover: false` depois de `keepStatic: true`

Comment: Cara ficou perfeito, muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom :D por isso gosto desse plugin hehe. @MauricioFerraz

Comment: use plugin CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.inputmask ... mais pratico ;-)

Comment: O meu aparece que inputmask não é uma function, porque?

Comment: @Junior o plugin que está usando é o mesmo do link da resposta? adicionou o jquery antes?

Comment: acertei o caminho que estava errado, mas para digitar o cnpj, eu tenho que começar a digitar e deletar um numero, só assim muda de cpf para cnpj, se digitar os numero ele trava no cpf e não deixa colocar mais que 9 digitos

Comment: @Junior Acredito que seja melhor criar uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Eu criei e utilizo essa solução à anos em jQuery para o próprio Plugin **Maskedinput** da **Digitalbush**:

```
$(".hibridCpf").on('focusin',function(){
    var target = $(this);
    var val = target.val();
    target.unmask();
    val = val.split(".").join("");
    val = val.split("-").join("");
    val = val.split("/").join("");
    target.val(val);
});
$(".hibridCpf").on('focusout',function(){
    var target = $(this);
    var val = target.val();
    val = val.split(".").join("");
    val = val.split("-").join("");
    val = val.split("/").join("");
    if (val.length==11) {
        target.mask("999.999.999-99");
        target.val(val);
    } else {
        if (val.length==14) {
            target.mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
            target.val(val);
        } else {
            target.val('');
        }
    }
});
```

> Teste esse exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chinnonsantos/k7ojrg84/).

É óbvio que a solução postada pelo [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray) é de longe mais simples e recomenda, porém há aqueles caso em que não é possível substituir o Plugin de Mascara da aplicação por N motivos, ai o jeito e improvisar igual eu fiz kkkk...

Essa solução server também para campos de CEP onde o usuário pode informar um Código postal brasileiro ou americano, usando uma lógica similar...

PS: Um plugin de mascara que recomendo e passei a utilizar é o **Mask Plugin** criado pelo Brasileiro **[@igorescobar (Github)](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)**, ele reuni o **[Mask Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)** e **[Mask Money](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/)** em um só com mais opções de personalização, vale a pena conferir!