# Como fazer uma combo Com os dias do mês?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer uma comboBox com os dias do mês?

Ou seja a combo tem de ter de 1 a 31 dias.

Do lado do HTML tenho uma label chamada "drpDia", e preciso de carregar essa label com números de 1 a 31. Eu sei que se pode fazer isso em JavaScript, mas eu nao percebo nada de JavaScript, então estava a ir pelo C#, em que sei mais ou menos que tenho fazer um list de 1 a 31 e depois tenho de preencher o label "drpDia" com esses números. correto?

Será uma coisa muito identia a esta?

Mas terei de carregar no drpDia.

```
int[] numbers = new int[seats];
for (int i = 1; i <= seats; i++)
{
  numbers[i-1] = i;
}
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(numbers);
```

exemplo:

So em que em vez de ter os dias da semana é ter os dias do mês onde está Friday passa a ser 1, saturday passa a ser 2 e por ai a diante até 31.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: C# ou JavaScript?

Comment: É em c# para apresentar em back office, o cliente tem de selecionar de 1 a 31 o dia que pretende

Comment: Eu não sei o que é **back office**. É pra devolver um `SelectList` pra View, isso?

Comment: Dê mais detalhes dos requisitos, como deve ser o critério. Dê um contexto, poste o código onde isso será usado.

Comment: Certo! o objetivo é ter uma combobox para devolver um selectList

Comment: @RicardoGonçalves isso você já disse, agora diga como ele deve ser. A gente pode ajudar, podemos fazer o código para você, que é mais do que o normal, mas você precisa detalhar como o código precisa ser feito. Não temos como adivinhar. Vocês que dizer o que deve constar no *combobox* (ou *dropdown* que eu acho que é o que deseja de fato e não um *combobox*) Quando deve aparecer cada forma, com base no que? Poste alguma coisa que está fazendo pra gente ver onde vamos encaixar o que está querendo.

Comment: Eu dei um exemplo acima, o objetivo é criar uma caixa onde o cliente pode selecionar o dia 1, ou o dia 2, ou o dia 3... a caixa so tem de apresentar os numeros de 1 a 31 e o cliente escolher qual o número que quer.

Comment: O que vc já codou até agora?

Comment: Do lado do HTML tenho uma label chamada "drpDia", e preciso de carregar essa label com números de 1 a 31. Eu sei que se pode fazer isso em JavaScript, mas eu nao percebo nada de JavaScript, então estava a ir pelo C#, em que sei mais ou menos que tenho fazer um list de 1 a 31 e depois tenho de preencher o label "drpDia" com esses números. correto?

Comment: Coloca tudo isto na pergunta, assim as pessoas podem te ajudar melhor. Já tá quase dando para reabrir.

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: Não tem muito a ver com o assunto, mas [eu fiz uma introdução ao jQuery (que é a forma mais fácil de você fazer o que precisa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138072/m%C3%A1scaras-com-jquery-telefone-cpf-e-cnpj/138088#138088)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem, acho que entendi sua pergunta...

Assumindo que você tenha o número do mês e um `ComboBox` vazio, podemos fazer isso em alguns passos :

**Primeiro :** precisamos descobrir quantos dias tem no mes:

```
 public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDiasNoMes(int mes, int? ano = null)
 {
    ano = ano ?? DateTime.Now.Year;
    return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(ano, mes))  // Dias: 1, 2 ... 31 etc. É um IEnumerable<int>
                     .Select(dia => new DateTime(ano, mes, dia)) // Mapeia as datas;
 }
```

**Segundo :** precisamos popular o `ComboBox`:

```
var itens = dataSource.AddRange(GetDiasNoMes(10) //Pega de outubro
                       .Select(data => new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Value = data.Day.ToString(),
                           Text = data.Day.ToString()
                       }); 

comboBox1.Items.Clear(); //Vamos garantir que estaja vazio
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(itens);
```

**Segundo (Alternativo) :** Utilizar Ajax do jQuery para atualizar

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Atualizar(int mes)
{
  var itens = GetDiasNoMes(mes) //Pega do mes 
                         .Select(data => data.Day);
  return Json(itens, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Mes", String.Empty)
@Html.DropDownList("Dia", null)

<script type="text/javascript">

$(() => {
   $( '#Mes' ).change( function () { //Quando o mês mudar/for selecionado entramos aqui

      let valor = $( this ).val(); //pegamos o valor

      $.ajax({ //Requisição
        url: '@Url.Action("Atualizar","MeuController")',
        data: { mes : valor }, //passamos o parametro para a ação
        success : ( lista ) => { // caso sucesso
           var dias = $( '#Dia' ); //dropdown

           dias.empty(); //limpamos as options

           lista.each( (index, data) => { //foreach
              dias.append( '<option value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>' ); //adicionamos uma option
           });
        }
      });
   })
})

</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Caro na sua primeira resposta o **paramento** deve ser uma constante, um número comum, passar no método `int ano = DateTime.Now.Year` não será aceito, não compila, do resto está Ok!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic realmente não percebi, fiz a questão toda direto na textarea do stackoverflow, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer isso de duas formas:

**Adicionando os 31 dias:**

```
List<int> dias = new List<int>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
{
    dias.Add(i);
}
```

**Adicionando a quantidade de dias de um mês específico:**

```
int qtdDias = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

for (int i = 1; i <= qtdDias; i++)
{
    dias.Add(i);
}
```

Depois adicionando o texto na label no evento selectionChanged do combobox:

```
lblDias.Content = cmbAging.SelectedValue;
```

Adicionando a lista no combo:

```
cmbDias.ItemsSource = dias;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por fazer assim, depois de investigar na net:

```
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["idDiaAmortizacaoCredito"]))
  {
       List<clDays> d = new List<clDays>();
       foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(1, 31).ToList())                    
           d.Add(new clDays() { day = x });                    
          LoadDropDownList(drpDay, "day", "day", () => d);

          this.lblDay.Visible = this.lblSourceID.Visible = false;
          this.drpDay.Visible = this.drpSourceID.Visible = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeito mais simples de preencher a combobox com os dias do mês e deixar selecionado o dia atual.

```
List<int> dias1 = new List<int>();
int diasdomes = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

   /*Preenchendo a lista com os dias do mês atual*/
            for (int i = 1; i <= diasdomes; i++)
            {
                dias1.Add(i);
            }
/*Preenchendo os items da ComboBox*/

            for (int i = 0; i < diasdomes; i++)
            {
                cbVencimento.Items.Insert(i, dias1[i]);
            }

/*Item selecionado da combobox como dia do mês atual*/
    cbVencimento.SelectedItem = DateTime.Today.Day;
```