# Mensagem JavaScript não esta aparecendo no input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom dia. Quero fazer com que o resultado da variavel cpf seja exibido no input 'recebe'.

praticando.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pratica.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset style="width:50%; margin: 0px auto; ">
        <legend>Colocando PONTO no CPF</legend>
        <form id="form">
            <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
            <input type="number" name="cpf" placeholder="Sem pontos e traço" required />
            <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="button"/><br/><br/>
            <input name='recebe' id="recebe" readonly style='width:100%;'/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

validaPraticando.php

```
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

if(strlen($cpf) == 11){
    $pegaCpf = substr($cpf,0,3).'.'.substr($cpf,3,3).'.'.substr($cpf,6,3).'-'.substr($cpf,9,2);
    echo json_encode($pegaCpf);
}else{
    echo json_encode("CPF Invalido");
}
```

pratica.js

```
$(documento.ready(function(){
$("#form").on("submit",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "validaPraticando.php",
        data: data,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $("#retorno").val(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("erro na requisição");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Verifica no navegador o que acontece quando chama a página validaPraticando.php, no success da um alert(data); só para verificar se está retornando corretamente.

Comment: Só complementando o que o @CaiqueRomero falou, no lugar do alert(data) coloque console.log(data) e aperte f12 para ver o resultado no console, porque se for um objeto ou um array não vai mostrar os valores usando o alert.

Comment: Não há nenhum elemento com o id "retorno" no seu html.

Comment: altere $("#retorno").val(data);     por   $("#recebe").val(data);

Comment: O navegador esta alertando esse erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". Referente a linha 23 do arquivo JavaScript. Essa linha é a ultima que contem "});".

Answer (score 0):

Atualizando aqui a resposta, se você quer usar máscara de cpf, use esse exemplo, junto com minha dica debaixo e ao digitar, já fará tudo automaticamente:

[Máscaras com jQuery: Telefone, CPF e CNPJ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138072/m%C3%A1scaras-com-jquery-telefone-cpf-e-cnpj)

Mas se você só quer validar a quantidade de caracteres, basta usar um 
`minlength="11"` e `maxlength='14'` dentro do seu input ficando:

```
<input type="number" name="cpf" minlength="11" `maxlength='14' placeholder="Sem pontos e traço" required />
```

Por último, se você quiser ver se o cpf é válido de verdade, pode usar uma função já pronta, fácil de achar em varios sites como esse:

[Como validar CPF no lado do cliente com script?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51340/como-validar-cpf-no-lado-do-cliente-com-script)

ou

http://www.devmedia.com.br/validar-cpf-com-javascript/23916

Answer (score 0):

Você está atribuindo o valor a um elemento que não existe `retorno`.
Verifique se a página retorna a informação desejada e corrija o campo onde ela será atribuída.

Mude de

```
success: function(data){
   $("#retorno").val(data);
},
```

Para:

```
success: function(data){
       //console.log() ou alert() apenas para verificar o que retornou.
       console.log(data); 
       $("#recebe").val(data);
    },
```

Comment: Fiz isso Caique Romero. Apertando F12 informa um erro no arquivo JavaScript, mostra a mensagem, "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". Referente a linha 23 do arquivo JavaScript. Essa linha é a ultima que contem "});"