# Inserção de caracteres automática em um form para validar CPF

Tags: php, javascript, crud

Amigos, estou fazendo um sistema CRUD e agora estou trabalhando nas consistências, e na parte q o usuário digita o CPF, eu quero que após digitar 3 números, um ponto seja inserido automaticamente, alguém pode ajudar??, obrigado desde já

Comment: Sugestão: [Plugin da digitalbush para mascara CNPJ e CPF no mesmo campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122147/91)

Answer (score 0):

Baixe esta lib (http://www.geradorcpf.com/jquery.maskedinput-1.1.4.pack.js) e utilize da seguinte maneira:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.1.4.pack.js"/></script>

<input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
        $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
    });
</script>
```