# Mascara placa de Carro em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não encontrei na internet uma máscara no formato *BBB-1234* para placas de carros, as que encontrei apenas validam quando o campo perde o foco e, mesmo assim, só dizem se está **válida** ou **inválida**.

Precisaria de algo que, nos primeiros 3 caracteres, aceitasse letras, adicionasse o traço, e, nos próximos 4 caracteres, só aceitasse números.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/01006330-99e0-4fe7-8ff4-8525969ec4b4/validao-placa-de-veculo-com-regex?forum=vscsharppt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar o plugin [RobinHerbots inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) além do jquery adicione o arquivo jquery.inputmask.bundle.js.

O código para máscara é composto por três letras (`A`) um traço (`-`) e quatro dígitos (`9`)

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#placa").inputmask({mask: 'AAA-9999'});
});
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="placa" >
```

[**Exemplo - jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qo2exdko/4/)

**Relaciondas:**

[Máscara de telefones usando jQuery Mask Plugin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112543/91)

[Plugin da digitalbush para mascara CNPJ e CPF no mesmo campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122152/91)

Comment: perfeito... obrigado

Comment: No firefox não funciona. Tem que fazer alguma adaptação?

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @rray, modifique a máscara para suportar o novo formato de placa:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#placa").inputmask({mask: ['AAA-9999','AAA9A99']});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

O código a seguir aplica a mascara padrao mercosul ou antigo, conforme usuario digita:

```
var MercoSulMaskBehavior = function (val) {
    var myMask = 'SSS0A00';
    var mercosul = /([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1})/;
    var normal = /([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{2})/;
    var replaced = val.replace(/[^\w]/g, '');
    if (normal.exec(replaced)) {
        myMask = 'SSS-0000';
    } else if (mercosul.exec(replaced)) {
        myMask = 'SSS0A00';
    }
        return myMask;
    },

    mercoSulOptions = {
        onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
            field.mask(MercoSulMaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
        }
    };

    $(function() {
        $("body").delegate('input.placa','paste', function(e) {
            $(this).unmask();
        });
        $("body").delegate('input.placa','input', function(e) {
            $('input.placa').mask(MercoSulMaskBehavior, mercoSulOptions);
        });
    });
```

O evento delegate faz com que defina um elemento pai para achar meu seletor, para caso de carregamento de conteúdo via retorno ajax. A cada input na tecla é chamado uma "função" que faz a validação da mascara e define se é mercosul ou normal

Answer (score 2):

- Reconhece padrão antigo(ABC-1234) e padrão novo do mercosul(ABC 1D23).
- Converte para letras maiúsculas automaticamente.
- Usa plugin jquery.mask.js.

```js
$('input[name=plate]').mask('AAA 0U00', {
    translation: {
        'A': {
            pattern: /[A-Za-z]/
        },
        'U': {
            pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]/
        },
    },
    onKeyPress: function (value, e, field, options) {
        // Convert to uppercase
        e.currentTarget.value = value.toUpperCase();

        // Get only valid characters
        let val = value.replace(/[^\w]/g, '');

        // Detect plate format
        let isNumeric = !isNaN(parseFloat(val[4])) && isFinite(val[4]);
        let mask = 'AAA 0U00';
        if(val.length > 4 && isNumeric) {
            mask = 'AAA-0000';
        }
        $(field).mask(mask, options);
    }
});
```