# Máscara para validar CPF e CNPJ no mesmo campo com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Preciso validar CPF e CNPJ no mesmo campo com jQuery.

Tentei esse código que vi aqui no site mas não funcionou:

```
$("#cpfcnpj").keydown(function(){
    try {
        $("#cpfcnpj").unmask();
    } catch (e) {}

    var tamanho = $("#cpfcnpj").val().length;

    if(tamanho < 11){
        $("#cpfcnpj").mask("999.999.999-99");
    } else if(tamanho >= 11){
        $("#cpfcnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    }                   
});
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Você colocou na sua solução o jQuery Masked Input também? Sem ele, não vai mesmo funcionar.

Comment: coloquei sim,
oq esta acontecendo é o seguinte, quando eu começo a digitar ele chama a mascara, porem os numeros nao saem do primeiro campo EX. x__.___.___-__  (sempre q eu digito só o "x" muda e nao preenche o campo todo)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94956/m%C3%A1scara-para-cpf-e-cnpj-no-mesmo-campo

Mesma pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Tem um exemplo em javascript que é fácil encontrar na internet, já usei em um projeto. 
**Javascript**

```
function mascaraMutuario(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout('execmascara()',1)
}

function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function cpfCnpj(v){

    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"")

    if (v.length <= 14) { //CPF

        //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
        v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")

        //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
        //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
        v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")

        //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
        v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1-$2")

    } else { //CNPJ

        //Coloca ponto entre o segundo e o terceiro dígitos
        v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1.$2")

        //Coloca ponto entre o quinto e o sexto dígitos
        v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2.$3")

        //Coloca uma barra entre o oitavo e o nono dígitos
        v=v.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/,".$1/$2")

        //Coloca um hífen depois do bloco de quatro dígitos
        v=v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/,"$1-$2")

    }

    return v
}
```

**Utilizando**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Máscara Javascript de CNPJ e CPF no Mesmo Campo do Formulário</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type='text' name='cpfcnpj' onkeypress='mascaraMutuario(this,cpfCnpj)' onblur='clearTimeout()'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```