# Máscara JQuery em um form

Tags: jquery

é uma duvida relativamente simples para vocês com maior experiencia mas eu não estou conseguindo por uma mascara em um form HTML.

```
<div class="site-element" element-id="1515038900431" element-type="skinInputElement">
                    <div>

                        <div class="site-element" element-id="id1427284680880" element-type="skinHierarchyBox">
                            <div class="element-children-container">



                                <div class="site-element" element-id="id1427284680884" element-type="label" >CPF</div>

                                <div class="site-element" element-id="id1427284680883" element-type="TextInputField"><input type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Nessa div a cima preciso de uma mascara no CPF por exemplo. Obrigado a todos

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Máscara para CPF e CNPJ no mesmo campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94956/m%c3%a1scara-para-cpf-e-cnpj-no-mesmo-campo), [Máscaras com jQuery: Telefone, CPF e CNPJ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138072)

Answer (score 1):

Existe um plugin Jquery chamado Jquery Mask

basta você adicionar a biblioteca do Jquery Mask e inserir o script

$('.seu_input').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});

// caso não queira que o cpf seja digitado de forma reversa

$('.seu_input').mask('000.000.000-00');

Abaixo está um exemplo funcionando, espero ter ajudado ;)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-mask-plugin@1.14.13/dist/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-element" element-id="1515038900431" element-type="skinInputElement">
  <div>
    <div class="site-element" element-id="id1427284680880" element-type="skinHierarchyBox">
      <div class="element-children-container">
        <div class="site-element" element-id="id1427284680884" element-type="label" >CPF</div>
        <div class="site-element" element-id="id1427284680883" element-type="TextInputField">
          <input type="text"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.site-element input').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
</script>
```