# Máscara dinâmica para os campos CPF, CNPJ e CEI

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask-plugin

Olá, busquei por essa dúvida nas perguntas, porém não a consegui encontrar. Pois bem, gostaria de fazer com que um campo tivesse as máscaras de **CPF e CNPJ e CEI**. dependendo da quantidade de caracteres digitados. Aqui não dá totalmente certo, pois com vários testes que fiz aqui, esse meu código não deu resultado que preciso. Não sei se devo apenas alterar, ou se preciso fazer outro.

> **O formato do CEI é este: 00.000.00000/00**

Eu tentei esse código, mas sem sucesso algum:

```js
$(".cpf_cnpj_cei").mask("000.000.000-00", {
  onKeyPress: function(cpfcnpj, e, field, options) {
    const masks = ["000.000.000-00", "00.000.00000/00", "00.000.000/0000-00"];
    let mask = null;
    if (cpfcnpj.length < 14) {
      mask = masks[0];
    } else if (cpfcnpj.length > 14 && cpfcnpj.length < 18) {
      mask = masks[1];
    } else if (cpfcnpj.length > 18) {
      mask = masks[2];
    }
    $(".cpf_cnpj_cei").mask(mask, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="cpf_cnpj_cei" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
```

**REFERÊNCIAS** 
**Máscara para CPF e CNPJ no mesmo campo**. [Máscara para CPF e CNPJ no mesmo campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94956/m%c3%a1scara-para-cpf-e-cnpj-no-mesmo-campo)
**Gerador de CEI**: https://theonegenerator.com/pt/geradores/documentos/gerador-de-cei 
**jQuery Mask Plugin
A plugin to make masks on form fields.**
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Levei em consideração no fechamento como duplicata o fato de a resposta ser praticamente o mesmo que já havia sido postado no link fornecido, tirando os ajustes. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Customização para casos muito específicos não elimina a característica da duplicação (e não é bem o objetivo do site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A máscara limita a quantidade de caracteres**, como você começa com uma máscara de cpf "000.000.000-00" o input nunca terá mais de 14 caracteres. **Coloque as máscaras com um zero a mais**, **para que o usuário consegua continuar digitando**.

E nesse caso em específico e modifique/simplifique as lógicas para ser "menor ou igual" e a última para um *else*, agora assim que o 16º caractere é digitado ele já mostra a máscara de CNPJ

```js
$(".cpf_cnpj_cei").mask("000.000.000-00", {
  onKeyPress: function(cpfcnpj, e, field, options) {
    const masks = ["000.000.000-000", "00.000.00000/000", "00.000.000/0000-00"];
    let mask = null;
    if (cpfcnpj.length <= 14) {
      mask = masks[0];
    } else if (cpfcnpj.length <= 15) {
      mask = masks[1];
    } else {
      mask = masks[2];
    }
    $(".cpf_cnpj_cei").mask(mask, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="cpf_cnpj_cei" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ótimo! É exatamente isso! Muito obrigado. Como tem pessoas que negativam uma resposta dessa se responde exatamente à pergunta?! Eu não entendo isso. Será se, pelo menos, leram à pergunta, clicaram no botão azul denominado "Executar"?

Comment: @TaffarelXavier , nao negativei a resposta, mas acho que é porque não funciona pro `CEI`, quando voce digita o útlimo numero do `CEI`, ele quebra pro `CNPJ`

Comment: A negativação é pq esse tipo de pergunta e resposta não bate muito bem com o uso ideal da plataforma, e muita gente apenas negativa ao invés de deixar comentários de como melhorar a perguntar, e deixar ela mais ampla para ser mais útil

Comment: Ai como é um problema muito específico com uma resposta específica acontece algumas negativações, sobre o erro do CEI aumente o <=15 para <=16.

Comment: Vou ser bastante sincero: tudo bem, é um direto negativar. Mas se o intuito não for ajudar as pessoas a resolverem os problemas delas, nada disso tem valor algum. E, mesmo alguns não aceitando a resposta, fiz vários testes, e funcionou perfeitamente para mim. Enfim, podem negativar ao ponto de eu ter que excluir a pergunta, mas meu problema foi resolvido, e é isso que basta pra mim. Outras pessoas poderão ser ajudadas também. O resto é o resto. Porque não tentaram resolver a pergunta?

Comment: Aliás @CmteCardeal o CEI está certo, a máscara tem um dígito a mais para não limitar a digitação, mas se digitar um CEI real a máscara fica certinho

Comment: Sim @TaffarelXavier concordo, o pessoal exagera um pouco, sua pergunta está bem redigida com código de exemplo, irá ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @SergioCarvalho atá, entendi errado.